Extending Theorem 2.49 to Lebesgue measurable functions; Folland
On page 78 in Folland's Real Analysis, he constructs a surface measure on the unit sphere, but only by considering Borel measures. Having proved this theorem, he remarks that it can be generalized to Lebesgue measurable functions by considering the completion of the surface measure $\sigma$.
The question is; how is this done? I understand the product of two complete measures may not be complete, so I don't see why we want to consider the completion of $\sigma$.
I'm aware of this answer, but I don't think it is providing much help in my understanding of the problem (and the user has been inactive for some time to ask for clarification).

Here's the necessary background.
Paraphrasing Folland on page 78, denote by $S^{n-1}=\{x\in\mathbb R^n:|x|=1\}$ the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^n$. If $x\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$, the polar coordinates of $x$ are $r=|x| \in (0,\infty)$ and $x'=x/|x| \in S^{n-1}$. The map $\Phi(x)=(r,x')$ is a continuous bijection from $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$ to $(0,\infty)\times S^{n-1}$ whose continuous inverse is $\Phi^{-1}(r,x')=rx'$. Denote by $m_*$ the Borel measure on $(0,\infty)\times S^{n-1}$ induced by $\Phi$ from Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$, that is, $m_*(E)=m(\Phi^{-1}(E))$. Finally, define the measure $\rho=\rho_n$ on $(0,\infty)$ by $\rho(E) = \int_E r^{n-1}\,dr$.

2.49 Theorem There is a unique Borel measure $\sigma= \sigma_{n-1}$ on $S^{n-1}$ such that $m_*= \rho \times \sigma$. If $f$ is Borel measurable on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $f \ge 0 $ or $f \in L^1(m)$, then
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x) \,dx = \int_0^\infty \int_{S^{n-1}} f(rx') r^{n-1} \,d\sigma (x') dr.\tag{2.50}$$


I think it is just a typo in Folland's book. What it really means is to consider the completion of $\rho \times \sigma$.

Hi @Ramiro, ok, that would make more sense. The formula $(2.50)$ looks a lot like an application of Tonelli-Fubini. If we have $f$ being a Lebesgue measurable function, I suppose we simply apply the complete version of Tonelli-Fubini (Theorem 2.39 on page 68) to $\int_{\mathbb R^n}f(x),dx$. Is that correct?

I think we also require a sort of change of variables formula for image measures, since $\rho\times\sigma$ is the image measure of $m$ under $\Phi$.

Yes, we consider the completion of $\rho \times \sigma$ and then we use the complete version of Tonelli-Fubini.  The formula (2.50) is a special case of "change of variable".

@Ramiro when we consider the completion of $\rho\times\sigma$, will this complete measure also be the pushforward of the complete Lebesgue measure $\overline{m}$ under $\Phi$? In other words, is the completion of $m_\ast(E)$ equal to $\overline{m}(\Phi^{-1}(E))$? How can one prove this (if it's true)?

Also, the change of variables formula for image measures isn't introduced until chapter 10, so it feels a bit strange to use it here.

Folland deduce (2.50) by itself, not applying the general change of variable formula.

@Ramiro ok, Folland derives (2.50) by knowing that $m_\ast$ is a pushforward measure, but how do I derive (2.50) when we consider complete measures, e.g. what is the completion of $m_\ast$?

A measurable isomorphism is a measurable bijection whose inverse is also measurable. The completion of the pushforward of a measure by measurable isomorphism is the pushforward of the completion of the measure.

The key step to prove this resulte is here:
Let $E$ be a subset of $(0,\infty)\times S^{n-1}$. Then, we have:

$\overline{m_}(E)=0$ if and only if 2. there is $N$ is a measurable subset of $(0,\infty)\times S^{n-1}$, such that $E \subseteq N$ and $m_(N)=0$ if and only if  3. $\Phi^{-1}(N)$ is measurable, $\Phi^{-1}(E) \subseteq \Phi^{-1}(N)$ and $m(\Phi^{-1}(N))=0$ if and only if $\overline{m}(\Phi^{-1}(N))=0$.


@Ramiro Thank you! So we have $\overline{\rho\times\sigma}=\overline{m_\ast}$, but I doubt how to use Fubini-Tonelli here to deduce (2.50). In his proof, Folland argues that (2.50) is just $\rho\times\sigma=m_\ast$, but now that we are working with complete measures, it's not necessarily true that $\overline{\rho\times\sigma}=\overline{\rho}\times\overline{\sigma}$. Hence, if all measures in (2.50) are complete, I don't see how it'll reduce to $\overline{\rho\times\sigma}=\overline{m_\ast}$.

So we have $\overline{\rho \times \sigma} = \overline{m_*}= \overline{m}(\Phi^{-1}(\cdot))$.

The next step is to apply the version of Fubini-Tonelli  for complete measure.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#For_complete_measures

Here is one approach:
Note that being a complete measure is more about the underlying measure space than the measure.
Suppose $f$ is Lebesgue measurable. Proposition 2.12 shows that there is a Borel $g$ such that $f=g$ except on a Lebesgue measurable null set. Note that $\rho$ is complete. We have
\begin{eqnarray}
\int f dx &=&  \int g dx &&\\
 &=& \int (g \circ \Phi^{-1}) dm_* && \text{Theorem 2.49}\\
&=& \int \left( \int (g \circ \Phi^{-1}) d \sigma \right) d \rho && \text{Theorem 2.37 b}\\
&=& \int \left( \int (g \circ \Phi^{-1}) d \overline{\sigma} \right) d \rho \\
&=& \int \left( \int (f \circ \Phi^{-1}) d \overline{\sigma} \right) d \rho 
\end{eqnarray}
